# Which package to install in Debian to get asoundlib.h?

Tags: debian, package

Trying to install Linrad for Wheezy.
But it complaints about missing asoundlib.h.
There is no package named alsa-dev, so which package contains asoundlib.h?

Answer (score 5):

Found in debian site:
https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=asoundlib.h

/usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h   libasound2-dev [not kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386], liboss4-salsa-dev [kfreebsd-i386, kfreebsd-amd64]

Answer (score 0):

Very old, but on jessie: sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev should do it.